# How does - [NSURLCache cachedResponseForRequest:] actually get the matching cache?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

How does **-[NSURLCache cachedResponseForRequest:]** works? Is it works like key-value pair where the key is the content of the **NSURLRequest** object (which includes the **NSURL** object, cache policy, time out interval, HTTPBody, HTTPHeaders)? If so then if any of the above field is different then we could not retrieve the cache.

For example, assuming the **NSURLRequest** has everything staying the same except the HTTPBody, which one request has the body of:

```
{
a = 1;
}
```

while another request has the body of:

```
{
a = 2;
}
```

Am I be able to get the cache of former request using the latter request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, only the URL is taken into account.   If header or body data dfferences matter to you, you'll need to implement a custom cache.  The URL Loading System Programming guide should be of some help, should you decide to go down that path.

Comment: Not quite true, I tried with HTTP POST connection and able to store and retrieve different cache for request with different HTTP body, in some cases. I'm thinking there is a limitation on the HTTP body (e.g. bytes size). But anyway, custom cache storing and retrieving should solve my case, thx !